# Tableau change colors of Dimension in one worksheet but not the other

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, worksheet

I have three piecharts in my Dashboard, each their own worksheet.  It is showing the percentage of completed tasks vs. not completed tasks for three different categories.  These categories have color schemes that help distinguish them from one another in other dashboards.  In trying to stay consistent across my dashboards, I attempted to change the colors of the pie charts to not only distinguish between TRUE and FALSE in terms of completed tasks, but I also wanted each pie chart to do so with colors similar to the categories they pertain to.

The problem is that if I try to change the color of TRUE and FALSE in one worksheet, the other pie charts follow suit.  How can I give different colors to the three piecharts individually?

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the TRUE FALSE field twice, then using a different one for the colour for each worksheet?

Comment: You can even try to combine category and true/false field in order to have 6 possible values, let's say:

A-True
A-False
B-True
B-False
C-True
C-False

It this is your scenario, you can select your plaette just once

Comment: boy, you guys are right.  That does seem to be the only way to do that.  It seems messy to have 6 different TRUE and FALSEs so that I can have different colors for 3 piecharts.  But that does work.  Thanks